# distinguish between Ah and 10 in x86

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers

How should I distinguish between `AH` as CPU register and `Ah` as number 10?

```
mov BH, AH
```

Comment: by prepending a zero (i.e. `0ah`), as the assembler surely requires. Or, use the prefix form `0xa` (supported by some x86 assemblers, like NASM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a zero in front of it:

```
mov BH, 0AH
```

Comment: What if there is no zero before A? I have seen `db B1h` as a valid code.

Comment: @barej `db` doesn't allow registers as operands because constants evaluated at compile-time are expected. Furthermore, `B1h` is no valid register, at least on x86.

Comment: So you mean it depends on the context?

Comment: @barej Well, `B1h` is, as I said, no valid register, so it's not interpreted as a register in **any** context. But, **if** it **was** a valid one, the `db` directive would definitely interpret it as a constant, i.e. `0xb1`.

Comment: What I want to know is not actually meaning of `B1h` as a human reader. But standards of assembler. Is there any standard?

Comment: @barej No, there's **no** definite "standard." Intel notation is `B1h`, AT&T notation is `0xb1`. Therefore, if you got an AT&T (at least by default) assembler like GNU as, `B1h` may also be a valid name for a label.

Comment: @barej, well, how do you know db isn't actually 0xdb ? It's *always* about context

Comment: But programming is about rules not context. However for `db` it is an operator(instruction) it cannot be a number.

Comment: @barej, and how would you know that? I suggest you read a little about parsers and grammer

Comment: @Leeor could you bring a complete instruction where db is ambiguous?

Answer (score 4):

In general, an hexadecimal number that begins with a letter will not be interpreted as a hexadecimal number in an assembler, as it can be confused with an identifier. This is why many assembler force you to either add a prefix "$", "#", or "0x" or begin your hexadecimal number with a digit ("0" for example, to not to alter its value), to avoid being parsed as an identifier.

```
MOV BH,AH  ;AH is a CPU register. It cannot be a symbol (equate or variable)
MOV BH,0AH ;AH is the hexadecimal value "0A" (10 in decimal)
MOV BH,$A  ;A is the hexadecimal value "0A" in some assemblers
MOV BH,#A  ;A is the hexadecimal value "0A" in some assemblers
MOV BH,0xA ;A is the hexadecimal value "0A" in some assemblers
```

Comment: Then, how does PE disassembler gives me `db B1h`?

Comment: A disassembler does not have to parse text input into binary output, it's the other way around, in which there is no confusion

Comment: I mean PE converted machine code into text. One of the obtained lines was `db B1h`

Comment: Take into account that we are talking about how a certain text input is interpreted: the text sequence "MOV AX,ABCDh" can be interpreted as either a inmediate MOV of the hexadecimal constant ABCD to register AX, or an inmediate MOV of the value of symbol ABCDh to AX

Comment: Does it mean that there is not strict assembler rules about numbers?

Comment: Yes, I meant that too. PE disassembler does not have to interpret text input, it produces text, and it seems that it produces it in a way that a later assembler won't be able to produce a binary output, as the assembler won't have enough information to find out if B1h should be read as a hexadecimal number "B1" or it is the value of the symbol "B1h" you forgot to define. In other words: that output from PE is ambiguous to an assembler

Comment: There are rules about numbers: any input that can be interpreted as a number and doesn't colide with another interpretation, is a number. The way assemblers asseure this is so depends on the syntax of that particular assembler. The different syntaxes I've enumerated in my answer are the most usual for hexadecimal numbers. Suffix "h" and prefix "0x" i've seen them in x86 assembler for DOS, Windows and Unix. Prefixes $ and #, I've seen them in Z80 assemblers to signal a hexadecimal constant.